# How do you properly allocate space in C

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program in C and I'm aware you have to allocate appropriate space for efficient code but am unsure of how to start, I've written and completed my program and it would be a shame to restart. If anyone can guide me how to properly malloc space for my program it would be appreciated.
Here is my code as follows:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "courses.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand (time(NULL));
    createStudents ();
    createCourses ();
    regiserStudents ();
    printCourses ();

    return 1;
}
```

courses.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "structs.h"

void createStudents () {
  int random, i;

  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    students[i].firstName = *firstName[i];
    students[i].lastName = *lastName[i];
    random = 10000 + rand() % 89999;
    students[i].num.studentNum = random;
    printf("%d - %s, %s \n", students[i].num.studentNum, students[i].lastName, students[i].firstName);
  }
}

void createCourses () {
  int numbers[999];
  int numbersLeft = 999;
  char courseCode[512];
  int numCourses = 3;
  int random, i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    numbers[i] = i;
  }

  for (j = 0; j < numCourses; j++) {
    random = rand() % numbersLeft;
    if (random < 10) {
      snprintf(courseCode, sizeof courseCode, "CS00%d", random);
    }
    else if (random < 100 && random > 9) {
      snprintf(courseCode, sizeof courseCode, "CS0%d", random);
    }
    else {
      snprintf(courseCode, sizeof courseCode, "CS%d", random);
    }

    courses[j].cName = courseName[j];
    courses[j].cDescription = courseDescription[j];
    courses[j].cCode = courseCode;
    numbers[random] = numbers[numbersLeft-1];
    numbersLeft--;

    random = 4 + rand() % 4;
    courses[j].maxRegister = random;
  }
}

void regiserStudents () {
  int checkSum = 0, checkSum1 = 0, checkTemp = 0, count0 = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
  int v, i, j, random;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    checkTemp = count0;

    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
      random = rand() % 3;
      if (random == 0) {
        if (count0 == 0) {
          courses[random].registered[count0] = &students[j];
          count0++;
        }
        else {
          checkSum1 = students[j].num.studentNum;

          for (v = 0; v < checkTemp; v++) {
            checkSum = courses[0].registered[v]->num.studentNum;
            if (checkSum == checkSum1) {
              /*Do Nothing*/
            }
            else {
              courses[random].registered[count0] = &students[j];
              count0++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (random == 1) {
        if (count1 == 0) {
          courses[random].registered[count1] = &students[j];
          count1++;
        }
        else {
          checkSum1 = students[j].num.studentNum;

          for (v = 0; v < checkTemp; v++) {
            checkSum = courses[1].registered[v]->num.studentNum;
            if (checkSum == checkSum1) {
              /*Do Nothing*/
            }
            else {
              courses[random].registered[count1] = &students[j];
              count1++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (random == 2) {
        if (count2 == 0) {
          courses[random].registered[count2] = &students[j];
          count2++;
        }
        else {
          checkSum1 = students[j].num.studentNum;

          for (v = 0; v < checkTemp; v++) {
            checkSum = courses[2].registered[v]->num.studentNum;
            if (checkSum == checkSum1) {
              /*Do Nothing*/
            }
            else {
              courses[random].registered[count2] = &students[j];
              count2++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  courses[0].studentRegistered = count0;
  courses[1].studentRegistered = count1;
  courses[2].studentRegistered = count2;
}

void printCourses () {
  int i;
  printf("\n%s - %s\n%s\nRegistered Students (%d/%d):\n", courses[0].cCode, courses[0].cName, courses[0].cDescription, courses[0].studentRegistered, courses[0].maxRegister);

  for (i = 0; i < courses[0].studentRegistered; i++) {
    printf("%d - %s, %s \n", courses[0].registered[i]->num.studentNum, courses[0].registered[i]->lastName, courses[0].registered[i]->firstName);
  }
  printf("\n%s - %s\n%s\nRegistered Students (%d/%d):\n", courses[1].cCode, courses[1].cName, courses[1].cDescription, courses[1].studentRegistered, courses[1].maxRegister);

  for (i = 0; i < courses[1].studentRegistered; i++) {
    printf("%d - %s, %s \n", courses[1].registered[i]->num.studentNum, courses[1].registered[i]->lastName, courses[1].registered[i]->firstName);
  }
  printf("\n%s - %s\n%s\nRegistered Students (%d/%d):\n", courses[2].cCode, courses[2].cName, courses[2].cDescription, courses[2].studentRegistered, courses[2].maxRegister);

  for (i = 0; i < courses[2].studentRegistered; i++) {
    printf("%d - %s, %s \n", courses[2].registered[i]->num.studentNum, courses[2].registered[i]->lastName, courses[2].registered[i]->firstName);
  }
}
```

courses.h

```
#ifndef COURSES_H_
#define COURSES_H_

void createStudents();
void createCourses ();
void regiserStudents ();
void printCourses ();

#endif
```

structs.h

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H_
#define STRUCTS_H_

char *firstName[] = {
  "Emma", "Liam", "Olivia",
  "Noah", "Ava", "Logan",
  "Sophia", "Lucas", "Isabella",
  "Mason", "Shaylyn", "Jack"
};

char *lastName[] = {
  "Smith", "Johnson", "Williams",
  "Brown", "Jones", "Miller",
  "Davis", "Garcia", "Rodriguez",
  "Wilson", "Seguin", "Loveday"
};

typedef struct{
  int studentNum;
}studentNumber;

typedef struct{
  char *firstName;
  char *lastName;
  studentNumber num;
}studentID;

studentID students[12];

char *courseName[] = {"Web Programming", "Technical Communication", "Processor Architecture"};
char *courseDescription[] = {"Learn to make websites!", "Learn the essentials of communication skills", "Learn the basics of circuits and Machine Language coding"};

typedef struct {
  int maxRegister;
  char *cCode;
  char *cName;
  char *cDescription;
  studentID *registered[8];
  studentID *waitlisted[12];
  int studentRegistered;
  int studentWaitlisted;
}course;

course courses[3];


#endif
```

Essentially the program should run as: create students, create random school courses, fill the students into the courses, and then print everything while accessing the structs from a header file (structs.h)

Here's the message I receive of running the program after it compiles:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it to find what causes the segmentation fault ?

Comment: I think `time` takes a struct, not `NULL`. If you don't need to create any new students or courses (and your lists are long enough) then you probably don't need to allocate any memory.

Comment: `return 1` in main? Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: You are calling those 4 functions in main, all of them includes a lot of information, you should call `printf()` after every function and see how many prints you see, then you know where you need to concentrate yourself. Something [like this](https://pastebin.com/raw/HcdAdL1f).

Comment: @TomasBy -- No, `time()` takes a pointer to a `time_t` `struct`, but: [If `timer` is not a null pointer, the return value is also assigned to the object it points to.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.4p3)

Comment: Compile this with `-Wall` and you will see your problem.

Comment: @frslm found the error, I was wrong in assuming it was a malloc issue since I'm not dynamically changing the memory. I was just improperly assigning values or dereferencing them. Problem solved! Will edit the file with the fixed code as shown in the answer below.

Comment: If you are on GCC use this flags, will help you a lot =>> `-Wpedantic -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-compare -O0 -g`

Comment: @Baris Yakut: I compiled with -g -o -w -Wall -pedantic -ansi and it didn't tell me where or how just that there was a segmentation fault!

Comment: `students[i].firstName = *firstName[i];` is an error -- if you do not see compiler error messages you need to adjust compiler settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `createStudents()`, you don't need to dereference `firstName[i]` nor `lastName[i]`:

```
students[i].firstName = *firstName[i];
students[i].lastName = *lastName[i];
```

Since `firstName[i]` already gives you a `char *`, you can assign that pointer directly to `students[i].firstName` (same goes for `lastName`):

```
students[i].firstName = firstName[i];
students[i].lastName = lastName[i];
```